# How make something after long click?

Tags: android, android-imageview, onlongclicklistener

I set onLongClickListener on ma imageView. I have a question - how can i do something after longclick? For example :

```
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

and after the longClick i would set Visibile my imageView. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried with v.setOnLongClickListener(View.INVISIBLE); ?

Comment: Do you mean when you do `onLongClick` the image disappears and when you release finger from screen the image shows?

Comment: Yes, i meant it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this and replace it with your code
Use on touch listener instead

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new imageView.OnTouchListener() {        
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // PRESSED
            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // RELEASED
            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
    }
    return false;
}
```

});